# Actionscript getBounds : what if the targetCoOrdinateSpace is not added to stage

Tags: actionscript-3, integer-overflow, bounding-box

I have two display objects dispObj1, dispObj2.
**dispObj2.stage** is null. (i.e. it is not added to stage anyhow)
What should be the output of **dispObj1.getBounds(dispObj2)**?
Is it well defined, or could it be arbitrary?
Once I got **x of boundingRectangle** close to **6710785**, which I guess
is a symptom of an integer overflow somewhere.

But other times I got a reasonable value for x,y,width,height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it returns some junk values.
Another person has faced the same problem.
Source :
[insane defaults for getBounds](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?p=1005552)